# Using different strings in C?

Tags: c, arrays, string

```
char *string = "a";
string = "abc";
```

The above piece of code is valid.

```
char string2 [2] = "a";
string2 = "abc";
```

The second piece of code is invalid. Why? Isn't `string2` a `char*` like `string`? How can the same type have different properties?

Comment: An array is *not* the same as a pointer. Never has been. An this as been covered on Stack Overflow more times than I can count (integer overflow).

Comment: [The C FAQ has a nice page on the answer.](http://c-faq.com/aryptr/)

Answer (score 2):

`string` is a pointer to a `char`. `string2` is an array of `char` elements. Those two are different types.

In your second example, you are trying to assign a pointer to an array (string literals evaluate to pointers.) This makes no sense and isn't possible. It's really no different from:

```
int numbers[2];
int num;
numbers = &num; // How's that supposed to work?
```

People get a bit confused by this, because you can use the index operator `[]` on pointers, and the name of an array evaluates to a pointer to its first element. That doesn't mean that pointers are arrays, or vice versa. That's just some syntactic sugar to make access to the pointed to or contained data easier.

Answer (score 0):

> The second piece of code is invalid. Why?

Because arrays names are non-modifiable l-values.

> Isn't `string2` a `char*` like `string`?

No. `string2` is an array of `2` `char`s while `string` is a pointer to `char`.

> How can the same type have different properties?

Do remember, ***pointers are not arrays***. `string` and `string2` are of different type.

Comment: The `=` operator does not copy data from one string to another. The problem here has nothing to do with the number of characters involved. It would still be an error if it read `char string2 [2] = "abc"; string2 = "a";`.

Answer (score 0):

In your second code you trying to assign new string to array.

In C arrays are not directly assignable. You can use `strcpy`

```
char string2 [2] = "a";
strcpy(string2, "ab");
```